# Change order for rdfs:label in Protégé

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

When creating multi-languages ontology, Protégé puts the first created label (or comment) in first in the .owl exported file.

For example, I have some properties with the English label in first:

```
<rdfs:label xml:lang="en">citeApparatName</rdfs:label>
<rdfs:label xml:lang="fr">citeApparatNom</rdfs:label>
```

I want to have the French label as the default one. It is possible to configure Protégé [to do this in View->Custom Rendering->fr](http://protege-project.136.n4.nabble.com/display-labels-with-specified-language-other-than-English-td4655748.html).

The order of English and French labels is not important in Protégé. **However, I want to export my ontology to an Omeka S website.** Omeka S [will only keep the first label](https://forum.omeka.org/t/ontology-in-several-languages/7461) in the owl file. Therefore, I will have an English label for the example above and a French one for the one below:

```
<rdfs:label xml:lang="fr">citeApparatNom</rdfs:label>
<rdfs:label xml:lang="en">citeApparatName</rdfs:label>
```

If I modify by hand my .owl file (putting French label lines always before the English ones), this action will be erased each time I modify a property and same the file with Protégé.

Is it a way to the French labels (or comments) always in top?

Comment: *Protégé puts the first created label (or comment) in first in the .owl exported file* -- it seems that Protege orders saved labels alphabetically (by value first, by language second). Hence: 1. Replace all `<rdfs:label xml:lang="fr">` with `<rdfs:label xml:lang="fr">!` in  your text editor. 2. Open your ontology in Protege, edit something, save the ontology. 3. Replace all `<rdfs:label xml:lang="fr">!` with `<rdfs:label xml:lang="fr">` in the text editor.

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thanks I was assuming wrongly it was the first created label in top. This is a good workaround but I am interested also if there is a other way (less manual).

Comment: *"less manual"* – by "replace", I mean Ctrl+H or something like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if you still have the issue.

In protégé 5 you can go to "View" menu, then "custom rendering", There, n the tab renderer, there is the option: Entity rendering. Choose there render by annotation property, and click in configure. At the botton of new window, you will see the option set language. There you have to set "fr" first. Click ok to everything, and then you will have all your default labels in French.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30910662)

Comment: Yes, it solved it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, the task you're trying to accomplish is to prepare the ontologies for export to a slightly different format - one that allows only one label per entity (even if it's still OWL otherwise).

What I'd do is delete all non french labels. Could be done with code parsing the XML itself or with OWLAPI code, so that you have a tool to run against your ontology every time you want to refresh the export you make to Omeka S.